# Delphi 2010 WriteLn to TextFile cutting off around 55 characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Given this mess (designed years ago to write some data out csv "field1","field2") the output file has began stopping around 55 characters.  Same happens in a showmessage() call or placing inside a local String variable. Converting to a TStringList to clean the code up even fails in the same way.  Inspecting this as a local string variable in the IDE while the code is stopped shows the entire built string as planned.  ShowMessage() even puts trailing ellipsis ... on the end.

I end up with "LD","BC63781S","JACKSON","MS","DENVER","CO","1186","0"... in showmessage and "LD","BC63781S","JACKSON","MS","DENVER","CO","1186","0" in the on disk file.

Better readability
https://gist.github.com/788839

```
Writeln(F,
  '"'+ ACtion
  + '","' + Ini.ReadString('IP_ITS','BAccount','TEST')
  + '","' + FieldByName('PICKCITY').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('PICKST').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('DROPCITY').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('DROPST').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('TOT_MILES').AsString
  + '","' + FloatToStr(AWeight)
  + '","' + FieldByName('LENGTH').AsString
  + '","' + FloatToStr(AStops)
  + '","' + ''{grosspay}
  + '","' + FieldByName('PICK_DATE').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('PICK_TIME').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('DROP_DATE').AsString
  + '","' + FieldByName('DROP_TIME').AsString
  + '","' + AEquip
  + '","","' + ALTL
  + '"' + ',"","' + '","1","'
  + Ini.ReadString('IP_ITS','BComp','BAccount')
  + FieldByName('PRO_NO').AsString
  + '","","","","",""'
  )
```

Comment: Your Git post says it worked up until today. So what did you change yesterday to break it?

Comment: =)) now that's a good question

Comment: Subversion confirms nothing has changed.

Comment: It's the double quotes (established by a third party vendor).  I can change the double quotes to _LOL_ or anything else and it's all good.

Comment: I wouldn't bother thinking about a possible bug in `WriteLn` or the likes. Although the problem is likely related to unicode/ansi, that line of code is in serious need of refactoring, and it will surely take you less time to make it right than to try to find why it is not working as it is.

Comment: Are you sure you closed and/or flushed the file properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two fix possitibilies:

1) Instead of the + sign between each string, just use a , instead. It will let Writeln() do the text concatenation.

```
          Writeln(F, '"',ACtion,'","', Ini.ReadString('IP_ITS','BAccount','TEST'),'","',
            FieldByName('PICKCITY').AsString,'","',FieldByName('PICKST').AsString,'","',
            FieldByName('DROPCITY').AsString,'","',FieldByName('DROPST').AsString,'","',
            FieldByName('TOT_MILES').AsString,'","',FloatToStr(AWeight),","',
            FieldByName('LENGTH').AsString,'","',FloatToStr(AStops),
            '","',''{grosspay},'","',FieldByName('PICK_DATE').AsString,
            '","',FieldByName('PICK_TIME').AsString,'","',FieldByName('DROP_DATE').AsString,
            '","',FieldByName('DROP_TIME').AsString,'","',AEquip,
            '","","',ALTL,'"' , ',"","',
            '","1","',Ini.ReadString('IP_ITS','BComp','BAccount'),FieldByName('PRO_NO').AsString,
            '","","","","",""');
```

2) Use a Format() then an open parameter array - this is my preferred way, because it will be also more easy to fix/maintain

```
  Writeln(F, format('"%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s",  ....
    [ACtion,Ini.ReadString('IP_ITS','BAccount','TEST'),FieldByName('PICKCITY').AsString, ..... ]));
```

And in all cases, make sure you've set a writing buffer of some size, and are using {$I-}:

```
procedure TClassData.SaveToFile(const FileName: TFileName);
var F: system.Text;
    buf: array[word] of byte;
begin
  {$I-}
  assign(F,FileName);
  system.SetTextBuf(F,buf);
  rewrite(F);
  if ioresult=0 then
  begin
    writeln(F,...
    ...
```

Comment: This was out - specifically what was happening is part of the file was written to disk and part in memory until CloseFile() was called.  Defining a buffer above causes nothing to go to disk until CloseFile() (or Flush()) is called to knock the buffer down to the disk.  I'm still not sure on why ShowMesage() puked on it.  The answer of course is to let it write it's data to the file before observing it.

Comment: @Richard: I don't understand very well your comment. Sorry. About buffer, there is a default buffer in system.Text. When the buffer is full, it's written on disk. The SetTextBuf() function only allows to make this buffer bigger, therefore reduce the calls to the Windows API for writing the file on disk, so it will be faster. The buffer was not part of the answer - just a bonus hint to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I may never understand the act of observing the string data forced it to truncate.  ShowMessage() and no stops it writes the file out fine.

Put a ShowMessage() or stop and no dice.

Quantum Delphi?

Perhaps a Flush call would have helped by why would ShowMessage() cut off at 55 chars?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enabled "huge strings", "range checking" and "overflow checking" in Project > Options > Compiler ?
Delete all your projects DCU files, and force project rebuild.
That may help.

Answer (score -1):

Your text file may contains invalid characters like #0 (end of a string). Consider a string like this:

sString := 'This a string #0 with a huge problem'.

If you do a ShowMessage(sString), it will only display "This a string" because a #0 indicates a end of string character.

Remeber that you cant actually see the #0 char, you may need to create a procedure to search for this char and delete it.

A better solution would be to not use TStringList at all, neither use Wite(). Use a Stream descendent, like TFileStream to get rid of this problem for good.

Comment: Sorry, but this was the contrary: ShowMessage was working, whereas writeln was not. And there is no track of TStringList in the question - perhaps it was a proposal but your syntax is not clear "not use TStringList". Write is not a very good idea in modern Delphi, you're perfectly right.

Comment: You wrote that "Converting to a TStringList to clean the code up even fails in the same way.". ShowMessage could work in newer delphi versions, because they have changed the way it works.